# Docker container eat memory and has large block I/O

Tags: docker, container

I try to use Docker and I have little problem. I don't understand why there is an increase in memory usage in my container. For example:

I have container with RabbitMQ, but it's not used. When I start the container, it has only 80Mb of memory, but after ten hours, it takes all limit (256Mb). I check statistics with `docker stats -a`.

Also, container has huge Block I/O

UPDATE:

RabbitMQ version 3.7.8

I used standart RabbitMQ-docker-image from docker-hub, but my server has't internet connection, and I had to use export/import.

`docker export rabbitmq > /work/tmp/rabbitmq-docker-image`
`docker import /work/tmp/rabbitmq-docker-image rabbitmq:current`
`docker run -d --memory=256m --restart=on-failure --hostname rabbitmq --name prod-rabbit -p 5673:5672 -p 15673:15672 rabbitmq:current rabbitmq-server`

Result of `docker stats -a`

CONTAINER ID     a0e8ad573154

NAME    prod-rabbit

CPU %   0.12%

MEM USAGE / LIMIT    255.6MiB / 256MiB

MEM %    99.13%

NET I/O   201kB / 361kB

BLOCK I/O     19.5GB / 31.1GB

PIDS     5533

Comment: Hello and welcome to AU.  In order to improve legibility, could you post a 'character' version of the image.  Thank you

Comment: Thank you for your involvement, I has updated my question